# Constructor for Bitmap from Stream is too slow in compact framework 1

Tags: bitmap, compact-framework

I have 'png' image with size 200x200. 8bit color. Image size is 10k.
Image is in memory as byte array.
Calling Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(bytes)); costs me about 60 milliseconds.
It seems to long for such image size.
I know that PNG is compressed image but still think 60 milliseconds is too much time.
Does anybody know faster way to construct Bitmap from byte[] ?

Comment: Why do you think it is taking too much time? What kind of device are you running this on? Quite some things have changed since compact framework 1...

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have to use old devices with CF1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not really be the answer you're looking for, but it is too long for comments.

I found that on my device the first time loading an image takes twice as long as subsequent images.

The `Bitmap` constructors accept a filename or a `Stream` which probably show the same performance. I Also tried loading an image using unmanaged code (a .bmp file for now) but `Bitmap.FromHbitmap()` takes more time (35ms) than loading the image from disk using [`SHLoadDIBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453720.aspx) (17ms)!

So as far as I can tell, whatever it is doing, there is no way to get a `Bitmap` object without that penalty. Perhaps by using unmanaged code to load and display the images you might be able to speed things up, but as far as I can tell the .png filter is behind a COM interface which requires quite some time to get right in .NET.

Comment: After loading several images speed is about same value 60ms.